# Embedding a json array within json object

Tags: java, json, jersey

Im using the following code to put up a json array within json object;

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PollingPoJo {

    int id;
    String topic;
    String description;
    String pollItem1;
    String pollItem2;
    String pollItem3;
    String pollItem4;
    ArrayList<String> pollingItem ;
    public PollingPoJo(int id, String topic, String description, String pollItem1, String pollItem2, String pollItem3,
            String pollItem4) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.topic = topic;
        this.description = description;
        this.pollItem1 = pollItem1;
        this.pollItem2 = pollItem2;
        this.pollItem3 = pollItem3;
        this.pollItem4 = pollItem4;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }
    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getPollItem1() {
        return pollItem1;
    }
    public void setPollItem1(String pollItem1) {
        this.pollItem1 = pollItem1;
    }
    public String getPollItem2() {
        return pollItem2;
    }
    public void setPollItem2(String pollItem2) {
        this.pollItem2 = pollItem2;
    }
    public String getPollItem3() {
        return pollItem3;
    }
    public void setPollItem3(String pollItem3) {
        this.pollItem3 = pollItem3;
    }
    public String getPollItem4() {
        return pollItem4;
    }
    public void setPollItem4(String pollItem4) {
        this.pollItem4 = pollItem4;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        pollingItem = new ArrayList<>();
        pollingItem.add(pollItem1);
        pollingItem.add(pollItem2);
        pollingItem.add(pollItem3);
        pollingItem.add(pollItem4);

        String jObj = new JSONObject().put("id",id)
                .put("topic", topic)
                .put("description", description)
                .put("pollingItems", pollItem1).toString();

        return jObj;
    }

}
```

Later on Im using the following code to generate the response.

```
@POST
    @Path("polling")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static String getCurrentPoll() {
        ArrayList<PollingPoJo> output = new ArrayList<PollingPoJo>();
        try {
            Connection connection = MyResource.getConnection();
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM POLLING order by id desc limit 1 ");
            output = new ArrayList<PollingPoJo>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                PollingPoJo trending = new PollingPoJo(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("TOPIC"), rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"),
                        rs.getString("ITEM1"), rs.getString("ITEM2"), rs.getString("ITEM3"),
                        rs.getString("ITEM4"));
                output.add(trending);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
```

But the resulting json response does not contain json within it. Though I have embedded a array list within toString , it is not showing up. How can I be able to sort this out?

Following is the expected sample response,

> {   "topic": "Fruits",   "description":
>   "My favourite fruits",   "id": 1,
>   "polling_items": [
>       "Item 1",
>       "Item 2",
>       "Item 3"   ] }

but it is throwing the following response,

> [   {
>       "topic": "Fruits",
>       "description": "My favourite fruits",
>       "id": 1,
>       "pollingItems": "item1"   } ]

As you could see, pollingitems contains no json array. How can I be able to sort this out?

Comment: Well, your `toString()` override contains this line: `.put("pollingItems", pollItem1)` where `pollItem1` is a String. What did you think was going to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PollingPoJo, you should have a collection with name polling_items. And in the constructor of PollingPoJo, add the 3,4,5,6 parameters to this collection.